# What's wrong with repeating entries in awk print statements?

Tags: windows, awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux, line-breaks, dos2unix

I was trying to answer [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69523319), about how to repeat an existing column.

I thought this to be fairly easy, just by doing something like:

```
awk '{print $0 $2}'
```

This, however, only seems to print `$0`.

So, I decided to do some more tests:

```
awk '{print $0 $0}'     // prints the entire line only once
awk '{print $1 $1 $1}'  // prints the first entry only once
awk '{print $2 $1 $0}'  // prints the first entry, followed
                        // by the entire line
                        // (the second part is not printed)
...
```

And having a look at the results, I have the impression that `awk` is more or less checking what he has printed already and refuses to print it a next time.

Why is that?

I'm using `awk` from my Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL), more exactly the Ubuntu app from Canonical. This is the result of `awk --version`:

```
GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2019 Free Software Foundation.
```

Comment: which `awk`? I just tried a test on `gawk` and `mawk`. I get `first secondsecond` as the output for `echo 'first second' | mawk '{print $0 $2}'`

Comment: Did you forget to specify the delimiter or did you just forget to add it to your example above? Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: Unfair downvote neutralized. I suspect you have DOS line break `\r` in your file that you should remove first.

Comment: @anubhava: you're right: I have just removed that DOS line break from my file and now everything seems to be working. Please write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Sundeep: I've updated my question, mentioning the `awk` version, but as explained to Anubhava that's not the issue: apparently a Windows/DOS line break is the root cause of my problem.

Comment: This dupe target didn't look right as this is `awk` specific question and there is an awk solution that works without removing carriage returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{print $0 $0}'     // prints the entire line only once

awk '{print $0 $2}'     // prints only $0
```

All these are due to presence of DOS line break `\r` in your file. Due to presence of `\r` unix output overwrites on same line from the beginning of the line position hence both lines overlap and you get to see only one line in output.

You can remove `\r` using `tr` or `sed` like this:

```
tr -d '\t' < file > file.new
sed -i.bak $'s/\\r$//' file
```

Or you can ask `awk` to treat `\r\n` as record separator (note gnu-awk)

```
awk -v RS='\r\n` '{print $0, $0}' file
```

Comment: As mentioned in the added tags, also the command `dos2unix` can be used for turning the DOS line breaks into UNIX ones.